# What will be physical interpretation of an asymptote?

Tags: geometry

What will be physical interpretation of an asymptote ?
I know how to find an asymptote of a function but don't know its physical interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

If the line $y = a x + b$ is an asymptote to the curve $y = f(x)$ as $x \to \infty$, it means that points on the curve for large $x$ are close to the line. That's the **geometric** meaning: any **physical** interpretation would depend on what physical situation you're modelling with the curve.

Answer (score 0):

Say the asymptote as $x\to+\infty$ of $f$ is $y=x$.

Let us write the limit and the definition of the limit to see the precise geometric meaning.

$\lim_{x\to+\infty} f(x)-y=0$

This means that for a fixed $\varepsilon$. there exists $M$ such that $M<x$ implies |$f(x)-y|<\varepsilon$

What this means is that $f(x)$ gets arbitrarily close to $y$ as $x\to+\infty$, as in the curves $(C)$ of $f(x)$ and the straight line $y=x$ get arbitrarily close as $x$ becomes large enough.

Now, for a physical understanding, we can, for example, bring in the case of charging a capacitor in an R-C circuit.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC_circuit

As you can see, as $t\to+\infty$, the voltage $V$ goes to $V_0$, as in approaches the final voltage. Graphically, the curve of $V(t)$ has the asymptote $y=V_0$ as $x$ goes to $+\infty$